# RTC - RFT connected through Adapter does not complete and give result

Tags: adapter, rtc, rft

I am trying to run RFT Script though RTC 4.0.4 via IBM RFT Adapter, but it is not going to completion even though the script run is fine. It executes everything but does not take the status bar to 100%. Its stuck at 70%. And there is no result for the execution

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved by restarting the host. I believe that multiple adapters need to be cleaned up/deleted if not used.